# How would you create a list with connected items?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I need your help :-)

- Is there an UI patter name for this liststyle?
- How can I build it myself in android?

This is an example [picture](https://images.mobile-patterns.com/1386265805385-2013-12-05%2012.47.43.png)

Comment: Its depends on you.

Comment: This is the Material design [Steppers](https://material.io/guidelines/components/steppers.html#)

Answer (score 1):

Check this library project
https://github.com/baoyachi/StepView.git

It is called as stepped view

Comment: Terrible implementation, ther eis no view reuse pattern, which would hit you hard with more than few items ... it would be better to use RecyclerView with some custome background ... yeah, it's my opinion and that's why asking for library on stackoverflow is bad

Comment: Thank you for the name of the ui pattern. I am going to search for a library which uses recyclerview ;-)

Comment: The material design steppers suggested in the comment is a good one